# C script doesn't works globaly

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I write test script in C, compiled it and put to /usr/bin directory, to execute it from anywhere like `mkdir` or `ls`. But then I wrote `$ test` nothing happen, if i wrote `$ /usr/bin/test` it works well. What I did wrong? I got Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Don't ever name your programs `test`, because that's a standard command in the shell. See e.g. [this `test` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html). And by copying it to `/usr/bin` you have overwritten any possible existing `test` command already existing there. ***Never*** blindly copy your programs to a system directory!

Comment: With no code posted, this is not even remotely on topic.  "My Linux command doesn't work" question belong on http://unix.stackexchange.com/   Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shells (such as bash), there's a *shell builtin* named `test`. So, when you execute `test`, shell builtin `test` is executed even though you have `test` in `/usr/bin/` assuming you have `/usr/bin/` in your `PATH`. When you give full path, there's no ambiguity there (like other binaries named`test` which might be there in PATH or builtins).

You can test this by running:

```
$type test
```

Name your binary to something else that doesn't interfere with system binaries or shell builtins. It's generally recommended to put your binaries in designated locations such as `usr/local/bin/` even if your binary is uniquely named.